# MySQL - Returning a value based on two relations on a relation existing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a store, which has unique products, which has unique properties.  So there are three tables: stores, products, and properties.  Recently there was a bug in the system which gave some products in some stores two different "name" properties.  One is simply "name", and the other is "label".

I need a query that returns store IDs that have products with two different names.

```
SELECT 
    stores.id
FROM
    stores
INNER JOIN
    products ON products.store_id = stores.id
INNER JOIN
    properties ON properties.product_id = products.id
WHERE
    properties.name IN ('Name' , 'Label')
GROUP BY
    products.id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT properties.name) = 2;
```

This is what I have so far.  I am trying to avoid subqueries as products and properties are very large tables, and I'm stuck at this point.  I can't logically figure out why this query returns stores that don't have both name and label properties.  I double checked and none of the products have two "name" or "label" properties, only one of each.  So that wouldn't cause a false positive.

Edit:

**Schema**

```
Table: Stores
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
domain_id int(11) 
name varchar(255) 
description varchar(255)
address varchar(255)
details longtext

Table: products
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
store_id int(11) 
price varchar(255)

Table: properties
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
product_id int(11) 
name varchar(255) 
value varchar(255) 
position int(11)
```

**Data**

```
Store Data Structure
{ id: 2341, domain_id: 4, name: "East LA", description: nil, address: nil, details: nil }

Products Data Structure
{ id: 6482773, store_id: 2341, price: "5.00" } 

Property Data Sturcture
{ id: 9132472, product_id: 6482773, name: "Name", value: "Paper Plates", position: 1 }

{ id: 9132472, product_id: 6482773, name: "Label", value: "Paper Plates", position: 2 }
```

Return ONLY store IDs.  In this case, it would return 2341, since it has both a label and name property.

Comment: It will be very useful if you provide the schema of the tables and a sample of data with the expected result.

Comment: I added the information you asked.  If you need anything else for data examples, please let me know.  I gave as much as I thought would be useful.

Comment: Do you tried my answer, it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to join the table **stores**, since you already have **store_id** on the **products** table, and you don't need any additional info (like name or description) from a store. Understanding this, i will go with the next query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT p1.store_id
FROM
    products AS p1
INNER JOIN
    properties AS p2 ON p2.product_id = p1.id AND p2.name IN ('Name' , 'Label')
GROUP BY
    p1.id, p1.store_id
HAVING
    COUNT(p2.name) >= 2;
```

Reference example: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4oAgpYH2YZnPfWZGBEfpDF/1)